# How to send and retrieve XML in curl/PHP?

Tags: php, xml, curl

I have to reproduce this flow:

page request.php call page response.php with curl with an xml attached -> page response read the xml attached and print another xml -> page request read and print the response.

This is the code I am using for page request.php :

```
    $xmlRequest = '<Main >
   <First>
      <Second>
         Detail 1
      </Second>
      <Second>
        Detail 2
      </Second>
   </First>
</Main>';


$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://localhost:8888/response.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmlRequest);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);


echo "Result :".$server_output;
```

In page response.php, I can't retrieve the xml just sent from request.php

```
header('Content-type: application/xml');
var_dump($_REQUEST);
```

`Var_dump` return an empty value, and same for `print_r($_REQUEST)`.

How can I read the XML sent?

Comment: im not sure but I think `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` has to be array or urlencoded parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FROM: [phpdocs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` has to be array/urlencoded string. Note if using array `Content-Type` has to be `multipart/form-data`. Here is an example. I hope this helps.

```
$postFields = array ( 'xml' => '<Main><First><Second>Detail 1</Second><Second>Detail 2</Second></First></Main>',);
...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data'));
...
```